# Apply linear models to subsets of data defined by several ranges

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, data.table, data-wrangling

I have a specific data wrangling task in R where I need to divide the predictor variable into *overlapping* "neighborhoods" (or ranges) and fit the linear model (simple/bivariate) to each "neighborhood" to obtain the fitted value associated with the *middle* predictor variable in *that* "neighborhood." I am approaching the task as follows:

1. I create dummy variables(one per column) for each "neighborhood"
2. I apply the `lm()` function to subsets of data, i.e. rows where the dummy variables are 1, excluding those equaling 0
3. I extract the fitted value associated with the *middle* predictor variable in each "neighborhood"
4. I end up with a vector of fitted values with length equaling the number of "neighborhoods"

My approach works when the number of overlapping neighborhoods is small. It is rather verbose when the number of overlapping neighborhoods is large. Here's a reproducible example (using mock data I created and in this case # of neighborhoods = 7):

```
# Mock data
data <- tibble(y = as.integer(rnorm(10, mean = 100, sd = 20)), x = seq.int(0,9))
# Create dummies
new_data <- data %>% 
  mutate(neighborhood1 = ifelse(between(x, 0, 2.5), 1, 0),
         neighborhood2 = ifelse(between(x, 0.5, 3.5), 1, 0),
         neighborhood3 = ifelse(between(x, 1.5, 4.5), 1, 0),
         neighborhood4 = ifelse(between(x, 2.5, 5.5), 1, 0),
         neighborhood5 = ifelse(between(x, 3.5, 6.5), 1, 0),
         neighborhood6 = ifelse(between(x, 4.5, 7.5), 1, 0),
         neighborhood7 = ifelse(between(x, 5.5, 8.5), 1, 0))
# Run regression model on subsets of data 
# Obtain fitted value Y at the middle X 
# (in this example there are three obs per neighborhood and so we want the middle fitted value # 2)
Y_hat_1 <- lm(y ~ x, 
                    data = filter(.data = new_data, 
                                  neighborhood1 == 1))[["fitted.values"]][[2]]
Y_hat_2 <- lm(y ~ x, 
                    data = filter(.data = new_data, 
                                  neighborhood2 == 1))[["fitted.values"]][[2]]
Y_hat_3 <- lm(y ~ x, 
                    data = filter(.data = new_data, 
                                  neighborhood3 == 1))[["fitted.values"]][[2]]
Y_hat_4 <- lm(y ~ x, 
                    data = filter(.data = new_data, 
                                  neighborhood4 == 1))[["fitted.values"]][[2]]
Y_hat_5 <- lm(y ~ x, 
                    data = filter(.data = new_data, 
                                  neighborhood5 == 1))[["fitted.values"]][[2]]
Y_hat_6 <- lm(y ~ x, 
                    data = filter(.data = new_data, 
                                  neighborhood6 == 1))[["fitted.values"]][[2]]
Y_hat_7 <- lm(y ~ x, 
                    data = filter(.data = new_data, 
                                  neighborhood7 == 1))[["fitted.values"]][[2]]
```

I'm always wondering if there's a more efficient way of tackling this task (perhaps with nested data frame or loops or any `dplyr` or `data.table` functions that can make this task easier). Any suggestions would be super helpful to me and greatly appreciated!! And, sorry for the rather lengthy question as I'm trying to be more specific. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One alternative: If you put the limits in all the `between` in a data.table called "rng" with columns 'from' and 'to', then you could do a non-equi join with "data", and run the model for each match in `i` (`by = .EACHI`): `setDT(data)[rng, on = .(x >= from, x <= to), lm(y ~ x.x, data = .SD)[["fitted.values"]][[2]], by = .EACHI]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fact that you want observations of x equaling the breakpoints to fall into both adjacent categories makes this more complicated, but this should work and be quite fast. In general if you're doing tasks repeatedly across data, it's easier if that data is in a long format rather than a columnar format.

```r
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(y = as.integer(rnorm(10, mean = 100, sd = 20)), x = seq.int(0,9))

setDT(data) 
lookup <- data.table(start=c(0,  0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5), end=c(2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5),neighborhood=1:7)
new <- data[lookup, ,on=c("x>=start","x<=end")] #not just an interval join, but also expands the data
new[,x.1:=NULL] #drop the interval join column since it's not needed

new[, fitted(lm(y~x,data=.SD))[2],by="neighborhood"]
```

Henrik's solution with `.EACHI`:

```r
library(data.table)
data <- tibble(y = as.integer(rnorm(10, mean = 100, sd = 20)), x = seq.int(0,9))

setDT(data) 
lookup <- data.table(start=c(0,  0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5), end=c(2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5),neighborhood=1:7)
data[lookup, list(.GRP,fitted(lm(y~x.x,data=.SD))[2]),on=c("x>=start","x<=end"),by=.EACHI]
```

Comment: Henrik and I came up with similar solutions independently, but his suggestion to use `.EACHI` is even more efficient (it avoids allocating memory for the entire intermediate table all at once). I'll edit my solution to include his approach.

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time! Very elegant and both solutions work perfectly! Thank you much!!